# Allow specific URL in htaccess even if htaccess rewrites a word from that URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following situation in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^laravel/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is specifically made to not allow people to visit my laravel directory.
However, I want to be able to load a specific file from laravel directory into other files, like this:

```
<script src="/laravel/public/js/app.js" defer></script>
```

The problem is the following:
The generated URL will have 'laravel' removed from it as per the rule. If I comment that rule, then that line of code that includes app.js will work.

I have tried several things with my .htaccess and searched for a solution, but alas, I am failing to understand, it seems, how .htaccess code really does the things.

Can anyone help with a rule to allow specifically that URL?
Or, if possible, to allow access to the /laravel/public/js/ directory without removing the word 'laravel' from the URL.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Instead of doing complex things with checking negated patterns in a RewriteCond or similar, you could just put a rule before this that matches that URL specifically, does no rewriting at all (`-` in place of substitution URL), and then uses the `L` flag to indicate that none of the following rules should be evaluated any more.

Comment: @CBroe Would it be something like this, then?
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /laravel/public/js/app.js
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R]` 

Or would I have to put the entire domain there?

Comment: No need for a RewriteCond, do it via the rule, that is perfectly capable of matching on the URL path. `RewriteRule ^laravel/public/js/app\.js$ - [L]` - and no R flag, this is not supposed to be an external redirect.

Comment: @CBroe I see. Thank you for your answer! It did indeed fix my issue. If you want you can post it as an answer instead of a comment so I can select it as being the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing complex things with checking negated patterns in a RewriteCond or similar, you could just put a rule before this that matches that URL specifically, does no rewriting at all (`-` in place of substitution URL), and then uses the `L` flag to indicate that none of the following rules should be evaluated any more.

```
RewriteRule ^laravel/public/js/app\.js$ - [L]
```